# How do I know the point of intersection of two lines in the given graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How do I know the exact point of intersection of the graph , I have denoted the point of intersection as B ( taken some random coordinates (1,2). Please guide how do i find the exact point of intersection in the given figure to place the point B at that intersection point :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,5)--(0,0)--(5,0)(2,0)node(b){D}--(0,4)node{A} (3,0)node(b){C}--(0,2)node(b){E} (1,2)node(b){B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Please guide will be of great help.. Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `intersections` library of tikz. Then you can define paths and get their point of intersection!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1}}
\draw (0,5)--(0,0)--(5,0);
\draw [name path=P1] (2,0)node(b){D} -- (0,4)node{A}; 
\draw [name path=P2] (3,0)node(b){C} -- (0,2)node(b){E}; 
\path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2,by=B}];
\node [dot=B]  at (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result cannot be deemed as beautiful, but the intersection was found automatically. Tweak the code to your will and so that it looks nice!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much , it is really great... thanks a lot ...God bless you